# Black screen when booting Ubuntu with amd graphics

Tags: boot, 22.04, amdgpu, mint

after creating a bootable flash and installing Ubuntu on the main hard drive and rebooting, unfortunately, a black screen is displayed for me, and the monitor turns off while the device is on.
I found out that the problem is with the AMD graphics card.
I can load the operating system from the recovery environment and I tried to install the graphics card drive, but it gave an error.
My graphic card is radeon rx 550 ddr5 4gig

Comment: See if you can boot with the `nomodeset` option: https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/409199